# EF add child to existing parent throws DbUpdateConcurrencyException

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Using EF 6.0, I have the following  code in my app

```
using (var db = new TrackingEntities())
{

   foreach (var p in points)
   {
      var parent= db.Parents.Find(points[0].Imei);
      var record = new Child()
      {               
          .....
      };

      parent.Children.Add(record);
      db.SaveChanges();
   }
}
```

and it throws

> Additional information: Store update, insert, or delete statement
>   affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been
>   modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh
>   ObjectStateManager entries.

Update:

Something weird is happening. When I test the code while in started it to debug, it works fine and add children to parent. But when I disconnected it from debug and run the code again, it throws the mentioned error.

Here is the models:

```
 public partial class Child
    {

        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string ParentPK { get; set; }

        public virtual TB_Parent TB_Parent { get; set; }
    }

     public partial class TB_Parent
    {

        public long ParentID { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }

         public TB_Parent()
        {
            this.Children  = new HashSet<Child>();
        }

    }
```

Comment: maybe mark the parent as modified 'db.Entry(parent).State = EntityState.Modified; '

Comment: Can you show us the configuration for the Parent and Child entities?

Comment: Can you explain why you're setting Children to a new HashSet in the parent constructor? That seems strange to me. If you remove that, does the error still occur?

Comment: It was wired that adding to record was okay but more than two caused error. DB was not created by me and when I asked db team they told me there wasa index/key constraint so when we changed key combination of records it was inserted.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the Child to the appropriate DB Set prior to saving.

Try `db.Childs.Add(record);` or the equivalent depending on how you've named things.

Comment: you mean I have to add it twice ? once for parents childs and once in dbset ? If so, I Still get the same error

Comment: Yes. In addition to what you've shown, does each child have a reference to it's parent?

Comment: Also, you don't happen to have a foreign key relationship configured between the child and parent?

Comment: I have used DB First approach and in database the relation exists.